# Getting a parent element syntax error here. Can't find it?

Tags: reactjs

Here's the code. Not much going on, but I'm getting a parent element syntax error?

```
const Review = (props) => {
   const attributes = props.attributes

   return (
        <div className="card">
            score={attributes.score}
        </div> 
        <div className="title">
            {attributes.title}
        </div> 
        <div className="body">
            {attributes.description}
        </div> 
    ) 
}
```

Where's the error?

Comment: From where are you getting those props, do you have a parent element ?

Comment: Yes, just solved it -.- I guess syntax wanted a <Card></Card> wrapping the element. It's my first go of React on Rails so I'm making all the rookie mistakes one can make.